# Invoking a .php file from jQuery's $ajax in an MVC 5 View yields error 405

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, cors

I have an MVC 5 application with a view that is supposed to send a JSON object to php file/module/method (I have zero experience in php!). the jQuery method looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: "ajax/ajax_get_sql.php",
data: {
  a_rules: a_rules,
  use_ps: use_prepared_statements,
  pst_placeholder: pst_placeholder
},
dataType: "JSON",
success: function(data) {
  var html = '';

  if(data.hasOwnProperty("error")) {
    $("#demo_rules1")
      .jui_filter_rules("markRuleAsError", data["error"]["element_rule_id"], true)
      .triggerHandler("onValidationError",
      {
        err_code: "filter_error_server_side",
        err_description: "Server error during filter converion..." + '\n\n' + data["error"]["error_message"]
      }
    );
  } else {
    html += '<pre id="demo_code"><ul>';
    html += '<li>SQL: \n\n' + data["sql"] + '\n\n</li>';
    html += '<li>Bind params: \n\n' + JSON.stringify(data["bind_params"], null, '    ') + '</li>';
    html += '</ul></pre>';
    show_modal($("#modal_dialog"), $("#modal_dialog_content"), html);
  }

}
});
```

However, Chrome tools show me error 405 when that code is called.
I heard that it might be a CORS problem, but I didn't find anyway to configure CORS on MVC.
any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

A work around to this would be to send the JSON to a different endpoint, handle the request in mvc (or web api), return the result to the client

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage GetSql(TheDtoClass dto)
{
    // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("http://path/to/service/ajax_get_sql.php ");
    request.Method = "POST";

    string postData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto);
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (postData);

    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream ();
    dataStream.Write (byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    dataStream.Close ();

    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);

    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
    reader.Close ();
    dataStream.Close ();
    response.Close ();

    return Request.CreateResponse(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseDto>(responseFormat));
}
```

You can read more about the WebRequest class here

[WebRequest Msdn Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The only change you'd need to make is in the actual url calls and modify the example to map your current state to the web request state

Comment: after heavy modification to the code above, I still had error 405 (method not allowed)

Comment: what do I need to do exactly to the php files? I simply put them in the Scripts folder of my MVC project, and tried calling them. Is that allowed?

Comment: @FiFo are you trying to call an existing service? If not then just reimplement the php into C#, feel like if you are asking to reuse an existing php file into an mvc project that would be a nightmare at best

Comment: it's so hard to port. I know nothing about PHP, and the code is so long. I could solve the problem at the end. Please chack my solution.

Answer (score 0):

If its a 405 Method Not Allowed error you can try to set the header of the php to allow access from all domains

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

using the php code

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

[More info here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Comment: that didn't solve the problem. still getting: the server responded with 405 (method not allowed)

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot of research I solved it with the following steps:
1- Setup IIS so that it supports PHP files, and hosted the files in IIS
2- Switched hosting my web app from visual studio debugger to IIS, so that I won't need CORS
and it worked without any problem

It seems to me that there was no php support in the hosting environment I was using. Sorry to say that I have no experience neither in php nor in how hosting works. I think I need to study these things ASAP.